# R function to evaluate the values in data.table columns against another set of values

Tags: r, data.table

I have columns consisting of answers to different test questions (e.g. Q1,Q2,Q3), and I would like to write a function that would evaluate those answers and create new columns with scores for each test question (1 or 0), where 'id' refers to different individuals.

```
  id    Q1  Q2  Q3
   1    4   3   3
   2    7   3   7
   3    8   5   6
   4    8   2   8
   5    4   6   8
   6    4   6   6
   7    4   6   5
   8    4   6   8
   9    4   6   6
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
 id Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1_score Q2_score Q3_score
  1  4  3  3        1        0        0
  2  7  3  7        0        0        0
  3  8  5  6        0        0        0
  4  8  2  8        0        0        1
  5  4  6  8        1        1        1
  6  4  6  6        1        1        0
  7  4  6  5        1        1        0
  8  4  6  8        1        1        1
  9  4  6  6        1        1        0
```

I've defined the correct answers and the new column names below, but I can't seem to figure out the function that would do something like "for the first question 'Q1', if the answer is equal to the first value in 'answers', return 1 else 0"... then "for the second question 'Q2', if the answer is equal to the second value...", etc.

```
answers=c(4,6,8)
newcols=paste('Q',rep(1:3),'_score',sep='')
dt[,(newcols):= function, id, .SDcols=2:4]
```

Comment: I'm afraid my `data.table` knowledge is poor, but you could do it with `mapply()` in base R. Would be something like `dt[,newcols] <- mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(x == y, 1, 0), dt[2:4], answers)`

Answer (score 2):

We specify the `.SDcols` with all the columns except the first one, use `Map` to compare the corresponding `list` element (i.e. column) with corresponding value in `answers`, convert it to `integer` and assign (`:=`) it to new columns using `paste`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, paste0(names(dt)[-1], "_score") :=
        Map(function(x,y) as.integer(x==y), .SD, answers), .SDcols = -1]
dt
#    id Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1_score Q2_score Q3_score
#1:  1  4  3  3        1        0        0
#2:  2  7  3  7        0        0        0
#3:  3  8  5  6        0        0        0
#4:  4  8  2  8        0        0        1
#5:  5  4  6  8        1        1        1
#6:  6  4  6  6        1        1        0
#7:  7  4  6  5        1        1        0
#8:  8  4  6  8        1        1        1
#9:  9  4  6  6        1        1        0
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with

```
> quiz
  id Q1 Q2 Q3
1  1  4  3  3
2  2  7  3  7
3  3  8  5  6
4  4  8  2  8
5  5  4  6  8
6  6  4  6  6
7  7  4  6  5
8  8  4  6  8
9  9  4  6  6
```

You want to extract out the Q columns into a matrix and then do a row-by-row comparison by transposing, comparing by column (because R stores matrices in column-order) and then transposing back.

You can then convert to numeric by adding 0, fixup the names with a quick `paste0` and then `cbind` this onto your original. Here's a solution:

```
> resp =  t(t(quiz[,2:4]) == c(4,6,8))+0
> colnames(resp)=paste0(colnames(resp),"_score")
> cbind(quiz, data.frame(resp))
  id Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1_score Q2_score Q3_score
1  1  4  3  3        1        0        0
2  2  7  3  7        0        0        0
3  3  8  5  6        0        0        0
4  4  8  2  8        0        0        1
5  5  4  6  8        1        1        1
6  6  4  6  6        1        1        0
7  7  4  6  5        1        1        0
8  8  4  6  8        1        1        1
9  9  4  6  6        1        1        0
```